# passing values from javascript to jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

i'm using the following script to obtain the driving distance between two palces.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        gDir = new GDirections();
        GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
            var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344;
            var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<strong>Address 1: </strong>' + location1.address + ' (' + location1.lat + ':' + location1.lon + ')<br /><strong>Address 2: </strong>' + location2.address + ' (' + location2.lat + ':' + location2.lon + ')<br /><strong>Driving Distance: </strong>' + drivingDistanceMiles + ' miles (or ' + drivingDistanceKilometers + ' kilometers)';
        });
    }

    function showLocation() {
        geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address1.value, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
            {
                alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
            }
            else
            {
                location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address2.value, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                    {
                        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                        gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

i want to store the value of var drivingDistanceKilometers in the database so i want to pass this value to another or same jsp page. How can i do that ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a request to your JSP with the `drivingDistanceKilometers` as a parameter of the request. The request could be sent by [changing the location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp), or by changing the value of an input in a form of your HTML page and submitting this form, or by sending an AJAX request to your JSP.

Comment: after making a form and providing the necessary inputs, i want to know what code to write in javascript to pass drivingDistanceKilometers as a parameter request. So that i can accept in the jsp page.